# Iframe content gets scrolled through page when position is fixed

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am facing wiered issue in my site [www.brandstik.in](http://brandstik.in/). I have Live chat app embedded in my website & it has set in fixed position but it gets scrolled through page. This problem only happens in homepage. On other pages it is working as expected. I noticed every elements which has fixed position gets scrolled. Please help me to resolve this issue. I don't have much idea about css.

[image]

UPDATE

```
.live-chat-app{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:20px;
    display:block
}

<div class="live-chat-app">
<iframe name="customer-chat-iframe" id="customer-chat-iframe" src="http://brandstik.in/livechat/php/app.php?widget-iframe-content&amp;domain=brandstik.in" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" style="display: block; border: none; outline: none; position: fixed; z-index: 999999; overflow: hidden; bottom: 0px; right: 50px; width: 279px; height: 320px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: transparent;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: A fixed element is support to scroll with you as you scroll. It is relative to the viewport (the browser), and not the website content. Try changing it to position: absolute.

Comment: @MitchelJager which position you are talking about?

Comment: Actually, scrap what I just said. I see what the problem is. Having position: fixed; on an iframe won't work well. Instead, wrap it in another container div and position that with position:fixed;. Also, remove the height: 100%; from your body, as it is currently leaking content.

Comment: @MitchelJager I updated code as you said. Please review it above in post. It still not solved the problem. I have updated it on www.brandstik.in

Comment: Add a div around the Iframe, which is position:fixed;